# Pyside QtQuick - Signal from QML to Python with 2 arguments

Tags: python, pyside, qtquick2, signals-slots

Does anyone have an idea how I can pass 2 arguments via a signal call in a QML file to Python? I want to use python as a backend. My idea does work for one argument, but not for two. What do I have to change or is this not possible.

Here is the Button (custom Button):

```
PButton {
    text: qsTr("-");
    onClicked: backend.change_value(teigInput.text, -1)
}
```

Here is the python backend so far:

```
class Backend(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

    u/Slot(str)
    def to_python(self, input):
        print(input)
        self.setDoughOutput.emit(input)
        setDoughOutput = Signal(str)

    u/Slot(str)
    def change_value(self, valueString, step):
        value = int(valueString)
        value += step
        self.setDoughOutput.emit(str(value))
```

I have tried changing brackets and different ways of passing, but with no success.